# How to mount host codes to container in docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a very simple code base like the following

```
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
package.json
server.js
```

My docker file

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

My docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine   
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

I can build and do `docker-compose up` successfully but I have trouble mount my source code to the container (meaning when I edit my `server.js` and refresh the browser, it doesn't change).

I am not sure what parts are missing. Can someone please help me about it? Thanks a lot!

**Update**: 
 When I inspect the container, here is the mount info.

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/Users/JJ/myApp",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "12e5a018e711511bfe14a8ea97465d7966696dc62a57727eeafd0de2b4a1e915",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/12e5a018e711511bfe14a8ea97465d7966696dc62a57727eeafd0de2b4a1e915/_data",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app/node_modules",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Why do you think `source` and `destination` are off? The first one mounts a host directory, the second one is not. So those look fine to me. Can you run `docker-compose run web sh` and check if your code `server.js` changes are reflected in the container file system? It should be.

Comment: I can see the file changes inside /usr/src/app, but I am not sure why it doesn't reflect when browser refresh. +1

Comment: That means your mounts are working correctly. Your node app that is run with `npm start` is not reloading on code changes. I'm not sure how you'd do that, probably npm server configuration that automatically reloads on code change.

Comment: @tayfun I see. That makes sense. Thanks for the help! Hope someone can help me on the reload setup in this post.

Comment: Take a look at Nodemon, it does exactly what you're looking for: http://fostertheweb.com/2016/02/nodemon-inside-docker-container/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code won't automatically reload when you change it. You have to restart the process for that to happen.

I recommend using Nodemon in your development environment to make this happen automatically. https://nodemon.io/

Just be sure you don't deploy nodemon to production. It's not meant for that. It's a development tool.